# Can you make title bar less windows with SDL in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sdl

Can you hide the title bar in windows (xp/vista/7) in C++ and SDL?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to set SDL_NOFRAME:

http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode